Unable to disable alsamixer mute
I installed Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18 drivers. After installation it told me to disable mute using alsamixer. The alsamixer won't open from the terminal. In settings the output is set to Dummy Output and no other option is available. I cannot hear any sound on my headphones or speakers. How do I unmute the alsamixer to get sound back?
Typing alsamixer gives:
$ alsamixer
ALSA lib confmisc.c:855:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_inum returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:422:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1334:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5701:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib control.c:1528:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL default
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory

Pulse Audio Volume Contorl is not detecting any sound cards.
PulseAudio Volume Control
The sound cards:
$ lspci -vk |perl -lne 'print if /Audio/ .. /^[\w]*$/'
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller
Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 3
Memory at f7910000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>

01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 High Definition Audio Controller [GeForce 940MX] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GM107 High Definition Audio Controller [GeForce 940MX]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10
Memory at f7080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>

alsa-utils, firmware-sof-signed and alsa-tools are also installed:
alsa-utils:
  Installed: 1.2.6-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.2.6-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1.2.6-1ubuntu1 500
        500  jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ apt policy firmware-sof-signed
firmware-sof-signed:
  Installed: 2.0-1ubuntu4.5
  Candidate: 2.0-1ubuntu4.5
  Version table:
 *** 2.0-1ubuntu4.5 500
        500  jammy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
        500  jammy-updates/restricted i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.0-1ubuntu2 500
        500  jammy/restricted amd64 Packages
        500  jammy/restricted i386 Packages

$ apt policy alsa-tools
alsa-tools:
  Installed: 1.2.5-2
  Candidate: 1.2.5-2
  Version table:
 *** 1.2.5-2 500
        500  jammy/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/statushttp://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntuhttp://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntuhttp://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntuhttp://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntuhttp://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntuhttp://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu

OS and Hardware info:
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
OS Type: 64-bit
GNOME Version: 42.9
Windowing System: X11

CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4570 CPU @ 3.20GHz X 4
MEMORY: 8 GB
GPU: GeForce GTX 750 Ti
STORAGE: 660 GB

